# Using variables in an array

Tags: php

I have borrowed beautiful *[Cokidoo DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#105257)* class, that converts regular DateTime to "ago format".

I'm developing multilingual web-site and wanted to replace `year ago`, `years ago`, `month ago` with variables.

#### Code example:

```
protected $strings = array(
        'y' => array('1 year ago', '%d years ago'),
        'm' => array('1 month ago', '%d months ago'),
        'd' => array('1 day ago', '%d days ago'),
        'h' => array('1 hour ago', '%d hours ago'),
        'i' => array('1 minute ago', '%d minutes ago'),
        's' => array('now', '%d secons ago'),
    );
```

Is this possible to do this without using replace methods?

Obviously this didn't work:

`'m' => array('1' . $month_ago, '%d' . $months_ago),`

Any help please?

Comment: May be this [stuff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)?

Comment: @Ostrovski Thank you and it could be possible. Other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That class would be much more useful if it did not extend `DateTime`. The only thing it does is *format* a date, it has no reason at all to *be* a date. It could just as easily create a `DateTime` on demand and work on that instead of `$this`.

If you make this modification (and appropriately rename the class to e.g. `DateTimeDiffFormatter`) then suddenly all the possibilities are open: you can pass a parameter to the constructor that determines the language to be used, or even better pass in some reference to your i18n component. Then for example you could have

```
// I have no idea why this was protected, and probably the class author did not as well
private $strings = array(
    'y' => array('years_ago_1', 'years_ago_n'),
    // etc etc
);
```

and

```
return sprintf($localizer->get_string($this->strings[$intervalKey][$pluralKey]),
               $value);
```

Finally, it's a really bad idea to assume that you can hardcode the format of the localized strings to "X minutes ago" and similar. The number needs to be part of the format string since in many cultures it does not precede the "how long ago" part.

#### Update

I adapted Ilia's candidate solution to bring it in line with the suggestions above; the result is [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AZHyQs).

Comment: Yeah, there is no reason to use `protected` but why we just can't use inside of the class, normal solutions, like the one that I called *didn't work*? Using `sprintf` is ok but it's not perfect, I think? Author of this class offered to use `gettext` which I'm not very happy with as well.. Is there anything else, you think?

Comment: I have English, Spanish, Italian, French, German, Russian and Japanese and it seems that `"X minutes ago"` will work for all of them, check http://www.youtube.com/videos?gl=US&feature=mh&hl=ja ;)

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev: What you suggested wouldn't work, and if it did then it wouldn't scale. `sprintf` is what 99% of PHP localization libraries use, including the original class you linked to -- it's perfectly fine. If you want to get more ideas, have a look at how well-known PHP frameworks tackle localization.

Comment: Alright, Jon! Thanks a lot! +1! I'll wait a bit and if there is nobody   comes up with some uncommon solutions, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: Jon, thanks for your suggestions and everything. Based on your ideas, I have finally come to the desired results! Please take a look at my own answer and comment please in case there would be anything you could say or offer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have apostrophes where you don't need them.

Are you after:

```
 $month_ago = 'month ago';
 $months_ago = 'months ago';

//Further on within the array
'm' -> array('1 '.$month_ago, '%d '.$months_ago);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's the part of the class and it doesn't work this way!

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggested ideas, I finally came up to a working multilingual solution for returning time difference.

Please be gentle on me as I am a complete beginner in the object-oriented style programming and this is actually my first task. I'd be more than happy, if you left comments or suggested ideas.

Special thanks to Jon and I'm sorry that I couldn't embody all of your ideas. I'm accepting your answer as it has very nice suggestions and explanations!

#### Description

1. In my database I have `added_time` field, which refers to the creation time of each uploaded video in Unix Timestamp Format, e.g. `1345284190`. 
   This timestamp is passed in to the constructor like  `new creationTime( '@' . $timestamp)`;
2. I have a special function which loops through each video and inserts 
   e.g.: Video was added *27 days ago*.

I have finally achieved this by using a beautiful example provided by Cokidoo on [PHP Time Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#105257) and have added support for multilingual web-sites, replacing `years ago`, `months ago`, `days ago` and etc,  with any text that derived from language file.

#### Tweaking

1. I have changed the initial values (i.e.:  *year ago*, *month ago*, *day ago* and etc), that were written in English (in order to be able to use them in multilingual web-sites) to something that could be easily processed, e.g.: `year_ago`, `month_ago`, `day_ago` and etc.
2. Then I have exploded the initial `$value` variable that was returning output, e.g.: *1 year ago*, *1 month ago*, *1 day ago* and used in return `sprintf` as was suggested.
3. At last I added `getLocalized` function that would connect this class with my language files.

This is the final and working code that throws no warnings (Warnings are enabled; *PHP version 5.4.6*). 
I have renamed class name from `Cokidoo_DateTime` to `creationTime`:

```
class creationTime extends DateTime {

    private $strings = array(
        'y' => array('1 year_ago', '%d years_ago'),
        'm' => array('1 month_ago', '%d months_ago'),
        'd' => array('1 day_ago', '%d days_ago'),
        'h' => array('1 hour_ago', '%d hours_ago'),
        'i' => array('1 minute_ago', '%d minutes_ago'),
        's' => array('just_now', '%d seconds_ago'),
    );

   private function getLocalized($string) {

        global $lang;

        $string == 'year_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.year_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'years_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.years_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'month_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.month_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'months_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.months_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'day_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.day_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'days_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.days_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'hour_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.hour_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'hours_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.hours_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'hour_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.hour_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'hours_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.hours_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'minute_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.minute_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'minutes_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.minutes_ago'] : null;
        $string == 'just_now' ? $string = $lang['global.just_now'] : null;
        $string == 'seconds_ago' ? $string = $lang['global.seconds_ago'] : null;

        return $string;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the difference from the current time in the format X time ago
     * @return string
     */

   public function __toString() {
        $now = new DateTime('now');
        $diff = $this->diff($now);
        foreach($this->strings as $key => $value){
            if( ($text = $this->getDiffText($key, $diff)) ){
                return $text;
            }
        }
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Try to construct the time diff text with the specified interval key
     * @param string $intervalKey A value of: [y,m,d,h,i,s]
     * @param DateInterval $diff
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function getDiffText($intervalKey, $diff){
        $pluralKey = 1;
        $value = $diff->$intervalKey;
        if($value > 0){
            if($value < 2){
                $pluralKey = 0;
            }
            $value = explode(' ', sprintf($this->strings[$intervalKey][$pluralKey], $value) );          
            return sprintf('%d %s', implode(array_slice($value, 0)), $this->getLocalized(implode(array_slice($value, 1))));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### EDITED

This wonderful solution, does the same thing though but has better formatting and structure (by *[Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon)*).

```
class DateFormatter {
    private $localizer;

    private $strings = array(
        'y' => array('global.years_ago_1', 'global.years_ago_n'),
        'm' => array('global.months_ago_1', 'global.months_ago_n'),
        'd' => array('global.days_ago_1', 'global.days_ago_n'),
        'h' => array('global.hours_ago_1', 'global.hours_ago_n'),
        'i' => array('global.minutes_ago_1', 'global.minutes_ago_n'),
        's' => array('global.seconds_ago_1', 'global.seconds_ago_n'),
    );

    public function __construct(Localizer $localizer) {
        $this->localizer = $localizer;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the difference from the current time in the format X time ago
     * @return string
     */
    public function formatHowLongAgo(DateTime $date) {
        $now = new DateTime('now');
        $diff = $date->diff($now);
        foreach($this->strings as $unitOfTime => $formatStrings){
            $howMany = $diff->$unitOfTime;
            if (!$howMany) {
                continue;
            }

            $plural = $howMany > 1;
            return $this->localizer->format($this->strings[$unitOfTime][$plural], $howMany);
        }
        return '??';
    }
}

// Packaged the localization stuff inside a class so that it's not
// just hanging around in the global scope. Not much to see here,
// a "real" localizer would have more features.
class Localizer {
    private $lang = array(
        'global.years_ago_1'    => '1 year ago',
        'global.years_ago_n'    => '%d years ago',
        'global.months_ago_1'   => '1 month ago',
        'global.months_ago_n'   => '%d months ago',
        'global.days_ago_1'     => '1 day ago',
        'global.days_ago_n'     => '%d days ago',
        'global.hours_ago_1'    => '1 hour ago',
        'global.hours_ago_n'    => '%d hours ago',
        'global.minutes_ago_1'  => '1 minute ago',
        'global.minutes_ago_n'  => '%d minutes ago',
        'global.seconds_ago_1'  => 'just now',
        'global.seconds_ago_n'  => '%d seconds ago',
    );

    public function format($string /*, $param1, $param2, ... */) {
        $params = func_get_args(); // get variable # of params
        array_shift($params); // remove first item, we already have it in $string
        if (!isset($this->lang[$string])) {
            return '[['.$string.']]'; // a placeholder
        }

        return vsprintf($this->lang[$string], $params);
    }
}

$localizer = new Localizer;
$timestamp = '1345284190';  // Example of Unix Timestamp
$datetime = new DateTime("@$timestamp");
$formatter = new DateFormatter($localizer);

echo $formatter->formatHowLongAgo($datetime);
```

Comment: I adapted your solution to what I initially had in mind; see the update on my answer for a live example. It doesn't work better than the above, but it is structured better.

Comment: I just loved it! It's great! Thanks!! ;) I've updated my answer!